# Not able to call a backend function 404 not found

Tags: node.js, express

I am running a Express application with Node in the backend. I have 2 functions in a component in NodeJS which I am trying to access from my service. The link for both are the same in the service. It is able to connect one of the functions from the service.

However, it is showing `404 not found` for accessing the second function in the same component. It is strange that the 2 functions from the same service is are giving 2 different responses (1 success and 1 failure).

Has anyone faced any such issue and if so how can it be rectified?

Some code for reference :

**component1.component.ts**

```
getallprojectcat()
{

this.authenticationService.getprojectcat()
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(

data => {
    this.data = data;
},

error => {

          this.loading = false;
 });
}

}
```

**component2.component.ts**

```
showprojects(moid)
{
this.authenticationService.getprojectslist(moid)
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(
data => {
    this.silver = data;
},
error => {
    console.log('some error');      
    this.alertService.error(error);
    this.loading = false;
 });
}
```

**the .service file**

```
getprojectcat() 
{
 return this.http.get<any>(this.studenturl+'/getprojectcata/')
.pipe(map(allprojectcat => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(allprojectcat));
    return allprojectcat;
}));
}

getprojectslist(moid) 
{
return this.http.get(this.studenturl+'/getprojects/'+moid)
.pipe(map(projectslist => {
    console.log("Projects List:"+JSON.stringify(projectslist));
    return projectslist;
})).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Backend .js file**

```
exports.getprojectcata = function(req, res){
     console.log("First Function");

};
exports.getprojects = function(req, res){
    console.log("Second Function");

};
```

The function getprojectcata is working in the first component. However, it shows an 404 not found on the getprojects function in the second component. I have checked the following things -

1. Routing does not seem to be the problem as it is moving to the next component without any issues.
2. We have also tried calling the getprojectscata through the same service in component and it worked.

Comment: We need to see your express endpoint, and your backend code. If you are debugging the BE, then all you need is postman (or something similar) and the BE code. All the `component` files are Angular right? `service` aswell. Not related to your question.

Comment: Yes, all the components and services are angular. I have shared most of the code in question. I would like to point out that we are using lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

For sencond function use .post in service and backend route also.

As GET requests is only used to request data. And you are passing moid in http.get which gives 404.

In post you can send moid data in params and in backend fetch data as req.params.

I hope it wil help you .
Share your code for better understanding.

Comment: Hi ashish, Thanks for responding. So POST will be used for insert or update purposes. However, in my second function, I am using the moid to fetch more information. Hence we used the GET requests.

Comment: Use can use post in place of get. Hence it work same as  get and you trying to do.